# How is the access_token value created in drupal/simple_oauth?

Tags: php, drupal

The [drupal/simple_oauth](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth) module creates an `oauth2_token` table. This table has a column `value` and I've examined the source code but I cannot work out how this value is generated.

To make this a little bit more complicated, I don't have this service running locally, and I don't have access to the remote server it is running on, I only have access to the database itself.

I am creating a Python service that is using the Drupal database (because reasons). I am able to generate all the required data except this value field.

I can copy the value field from one of the existing access tokens, and use it in a new record I create via a SQL `INSERT`. The JWT I create from this record's value works correctly with the protected endpoint. However, if I set an arbitrary `value` like a UUID, the request to the protected resource fails with the following error response:

```
{
    "error": "permission_denied",
    "error_description": "The 'debug simple_oauth tokens' permission is required.",
    "status_code": 403,
    "detail": "permission_denied"
}
```

The value is used in the `jti` of the JWT and I can see in [src/Entities/AccessTokenEntity.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/-/blob/5.2.x/src/Entities/AccessTokenEntity.php) that this is set to `$this->getIdentifier();` (`<-- comments are mine`):

```
  public function convertToJWT() {
    $private_claims = [];
    \Drupal::moduleHandler()
      ->alter('simple_oauth_private_claims', $private_claims, $this);
    if (!is_array($private_claims)) {
      $message = 'An implementation of hook_simple_oauth_private_claims_alter ';
      $message .= 'returns an invalid $private_claims value. $private_claims ';
      $message .= 'must be an array.';
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException($message);
    }

    $id = $this->getIdentifier();  /* <-- NOTE */
    $now = new \DateTimeImmutable('@' . \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime());
    $key_path = $this->privateKey->getKeyPath();
    $key = InMemory::file($key_path);
    $config = Configuration::forSymmetricSigner(new Sha256(), $key);

    $builder = $config->builder()
      ->permittedFor($this->getClient()->getIdentifier())
      ->identifiedBy($id)  /* <-- SET THE JTI */
      ->withHeader('jti', $id)
      ->issuedAt($now)
      ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($now)
      ->expiresAt($this->getExpiryDateTime())
      ->relatedTo($this->getUserIdentifier())
      ->withClaim('scope', $this->getScopes());
```

And this is where my investigation has stopped, as I cannot work out where `getIdentifier()` is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross-posted this question to [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/313283/how-is-the-access-token-value-created#comment399699_313283) and @apaderno noted this wasn't a Drupal specific question, which nudged me towards the source for The source for [PHP OAuth 2.0 Server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server).

The source of the `value` column is the `generateUniqueIdentifier` function in [AbstractGrant.php](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/Grant/AbstractGrant.php#L569-L583):

```
    /**
     * Generate a new unique identifier.
     *
     * @param int $length
     *
     * @throws OAuthServerException
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function generateUniqueIdentifier($length = 40)
    {
        try {
            return \bin2hex(\random_bytes($length));
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        } catch (TypeError $e) {
            throw OAuthServerException::serverError('An unexpected error has occurred', $e);
        } catch (Error $e) {
            throw OAuthServerException::serverError('An unexpected error has occurred', $e);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // If you get this message, the CSPRNG failed hard.
            throw OAuthServerException::serverError('Could not generate a random string', $e);
        }
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
```